# Regular expression where part of the pattern is optional.

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a crossword compiler.

As an example lets say there are 8 blank spots with 'U' in the second spot, 'E' in the 4th spot and 'E' in the 6th spot.

_U_E_E___

I have a word list from which I am trying to get the words which match this. If I find an 8 letter word with this pattern(TUBELESS), great!. But if I can find a 4 letter word which only matches the first 4 slots(TUBE), I could work with that as well.

I could have one RE for each possible length and combine them using '|' but I am looking for a more elegant solution. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested optional groups: `.U.E(?:.(?:E(?:..?)?)?)?$`

You can use a simple recursive function to build the pattern: (almost the same pattern but even the last character get wrapped in a group)

```
def nested_pattern(s):
    if s:
        return '(?:' + s[0] + nested_pattern(s[1:]) + ')?'
    else:
        return ''

import re
regex = re.compile(r'.U.E' + nested_pattern(r'.E..') + '$')

for word in ('TUB', 'TUBE', 'TEBU', 'TUBES', 'PURETE', 'TUBELEX', 'TUBELESS', 'SURELY'):
    print word, bool(regex.match(word))
```

prints

```
TUB False
TUBE True
TEBU False
TUBES True
PURETE True
TUBELEX True
TUBELESS True
SURELY False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more succinct regular expression. I'm assuming the words in your dictionary won't have digits, so matching alphanumeric characters won't be problem. If that's not the case, just replace `\w` with `[A-Z]` in the expression.

```
import re

#REGEX EDIT:
#added so that the expression can't be embedded in another string
# ^ = beginning, $ = end

#to match words that are either 4 or 8 characters long:
#specify a group of 4 letters at the end, then match it 0 or 1 times with "?"
regex = re.compile(r"^\wU\wE(\wE\w{2})?$")

x = 'TUBELESS'
y = 'TUBE'

#both these options return a match object
#meaning they fit the regular expression
regex.match(x)
regex.match(y)
```

Comment: Ref: http://www.pythonregex.com/  Both 'TUBE' and 'TUBEXXX' would return match objects with the given RE which would not fit what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: you're right. i forgot that the match function returns true if it finds the expression anywhere inside a string. i added the beginning and end character to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

A 4 to 8 character string with the matches you want is:

```
>>> p = re.compile('^[A-Z]U[A-Z]E(?=[A-Z](?=E(?=[A-Z](?=[A-Z]$|$)|$)|$)|$)')
>>> re.match(p, 'TUB')
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBE')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe55ac0>
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBX')
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBEL')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe55b28>
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBELE')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe55ac0>
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBELEX')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe55b28>
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBELES')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe55ac0>
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBELESS')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe55b28>
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBELESSY')
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBELESS7')
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBELEZZ')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe55ac0>
>>> re.match(p, 'TUBELE88')
```

I'm not sure if this is "more elegant" but it is an interesting illustration of lookahead.  Maybe it will generate some ideas for you?

Comment: This is indeed an interesting use of look ahead and will do what I want to do. But I have to go with Janne Karila for a more comprehensive answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "_U_E_E___"
def solve(text, word_list):
    for word in word_list:
        matches = 0
        for c1, c2 in zip(text, word):
            if not(c1 == c2 or c1 == '_'):
                break
            matches += 1 
        if matches >= 4:
            return word


print solve(text, ['TXBELESS', 'TUBE'])
print solve(text, ['TXBELESS', 'TUBx', 'TUBELESS', 'TUBEL'])
```

**output:**

```
TUBE
TUBELESS
```

Comment: Although this code will work, I was looking for a regular expression.